# How to predict test data on Gensim Topic modelling

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gensim, topic-modeling, mallet

I have used Gensim LDAMallet for topic modelling but in what way we can predict sample paragraph and get their topic model using pretrained model.

```
# Build the bigram and trigram models
bigram = gensim.models.Phrases(t_preprocess(dataset.data), min_count=5, threshold=100)
bigram_mod = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(bigram) 

def make_bigrams(texts):
   return [bigram_mod[doc] for doc in texts]

data_words_bigrams = make_bigrams(t_preprocess(dataset.data))

# Create Dictionary
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_words_bigrams)

# Create Corpus
texts = data_words_bigrams

# Term Document Frequency
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

mallet_path='/home/riteshjain/anaconda3/mallet/mallet2.0.8/bin/mallet' 
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path,corpus=corpus, num_topics=12, id2word=id2word, random_seed = 0)

coherence_model_ldamallet = CoherenceModel(model=ldamallet, texts=texts, dictionary=id2word, coherence='c_v')

a = "When Honda builds a hybrid, you've got to be sure it‚Äôs a marvel. And an Accord Hybrid is when technology surpasses the known and takes a leap of faith into tomorrow. This is the next generation Accord, the ninth generation to be precise."
```

How to use this text (a) to get its topic from the pretrained model. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to process 'a' similarly to the trained set:

```html
# import a new data set to be passed through the pre-trained LDA

data_new = pd.read_csv('YourNew.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1");
data_new = data_new.dropna()
data_text_new = data_new[['Your Target Column']]
data_text_new['index'] = data_text_new.index

documents_new = data_text_new

# process the new data set through the lemmatization, and stopwork functions

def preprocess(text):
    result = []
    for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
        if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and len(token) > 3:
            nltk.bigrams(token)
            result.append(lemmatize_stemming(token))
    return result

processed_docs_new = documents_new['Your Target Column'].map(preprocess)

# create a dictionary of individual words and filter the dictionary
dictionary_new = gensim.corpora.Dictionary(processed_docs_new[:])
dictionary_new.filter_extremes(no_below=15, no_above=0.5, keep_n=100000)

# define the bow_corpus
bow_corpus_new = [dictionary_new.doc2bow(doc) for doc in processed_docs_new]
```

Then you can just pass it through as a function:

```html
a = ldamallet[bow_corpus_new[:len(bow_corpus_new)]]
b = data_text_new

topic_0=[]
topic_1=[]
topic_2=[]

for i in a:
    topic_0.append(i[0][1])
    topic_1.append(i[1][1])
    topic_2.append(i[2][1])
    
d = {'Your Target Column': b['Your Target Column'].tolist(),
     'topic_0': topic_0,
     'topic_1': topic_1,
     'topic_2': topic_2}
     
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_csv("YourAllocated.csv", index=True, mode = 'a')
```

I hope this helps :)